# How to bind dynamic property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am parsing some Json data that Contains Json objects as

- "0": "some data" ,
- "1" : "other data".

After converting it to c# classes , code converted as :

```
public class Data
{
    public List<Items> photos { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
    public string __invalid_name__3 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__0 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__2 { get; set; }
}
```

This data won't deserialize properly . I have tried both Jsoncovert as well as DataContract deserializer.

So I took

```
List<Items> as List<dynamic>.
```

But the problem is keys name are still as "0" , "1" and this won't be able to bind to my xaml UI end.

Is there any way to bind this dynamic data to UI?

Comment: I can not figure out what you are asking

Comment: Can you show the JSON string, this might help us with an answer.

Comment: Can you post your XAML? How did you try to bind Items object's properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the DataContractJsonSerializer you can set the Name property on your DataMemberAttributes to serialize the object with different names than the names of your properties in C#:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Data
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<Items> photos { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Items
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "3")]
        public string Three { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name="0")]
        public string Zero { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "2")]
        public string Two { get; set; }
    }

    public static void TestJson()
    {
        var json = "{\"photos\":[{\"0\":\"some data\",\"2\":\"other data\",\"3\":\"another data\"}]}";

        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Data));
        Data data = serializer.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json))) as Data;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @tyler. U got me correctly. Ur solution is useful :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this parse:

```
var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonString = /*your json string*/

var yourList = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<YourClass>>(jsonString);

public class YourClass
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "0")]
    public string Zero { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "1")]
    public string One { get; set; }
}
```

This is working for me ;]

Comment: Property names cannot start with a digit!

Comment: I gave an example solution of the serializer not the model. Anyway I've editted the model so its using the correct anotation ;]